# json.stringify posted to my php file, bt on json_decode showing error undefinedm please check error

Tags: jquery, json

**jQuery code** 
**jsonString** = JSON.stringify(arrReturn);
$.ajax({ 
           **url**:                'add-performa-invoice.php', 
           **method**:      'post', 
           **data**:             {'pro_table': jsonString}, 
           **success**:    function(data, status, jqXHR){ 
                                    if(status == 'success'){ 
                                              $('#myLoading').modal('hide'); 
                                              setTimeout("window.location.href='add-performa-invoice.php?id'",800); 
                                    } 
           },
           **error**:         function(jqXHR, status, error){ 
                                    if(status != 'success'){ 
                                              $("#myError").modal("show"); 
                                    } 
            } 
}); 

**ON my consol.log(jsonString)** 
//result is (this is the data of three rows where "0", "1", "2" are row indexs )
{
"**0**": {"proName":"Thresds","proConst":"618","problend":"48","proGriege":"48","proFinish":"48","proProces":"4","proQuntty":"84","proPricee":"84","proAmount":"7056","proValue":"1"},
"**1**":
{"proName":"Car Break ","proConst":"584","problend":"84","proGriege":"8","proFinish":"15","proProces":"18","proQuntty":"45","proPricee":"512","proAmount":"225","proValue":"2"},
"**2**":
{"proName":"Thresds","proConst":"848478","problend":"78","proGriege":"748","proFinish":"78","proProces":"784","proQuntty":"48","proPricee":"4","proAmount":"192","proValue":"1"}
}

**//PHP** 
in add-performa-invoice.php file i m receing data like

$pro_table = json_decode($_POST['pro_teble']);
if(is_object($pro_table)){
        echo "its object";
}else{
        echo "its not object";
}
**//but**
here output is
Undefined index: **pro_teble**

Comment: For your future posts: add a new line before your code, select the code and press Ctrl + K. In this way, the indentation will be preserved and the code will have a grey background. It's easier.

Comment: What you have done @goodMan???

Comment: there was an typographical error, i found it
i m very thankful to you all guys for helping me regarding my Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var newParamString = {pro_teble: jsonString}


data:newParamString ,
```

You dont need to do json_decode at server end just do $_POST

Let me know what error you get if any